# Highlight Rows Between Start and End time

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Basically I need a formula to highlight cell if the time mentioned in a Cell is between the Given Start and end time
Time that needs to be highlighted: 17:35:00, Start time: 17:30:00 End Time 02:30:00

Comment: READ [THIS](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1727-excel-conditional-formatting-between-two-dates.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have times in A2:A, you can use OR with ISBETWEEN to tackle this. You'll cover the block from 1730 to 23:59:59 and then 0 (12am) to 02:30

```
=AND(LEN($A2),OR(ISBETWEEN($A2,TIME(17,30,0),TIME(23,59,59)),ISBETWEEN($A2,0,TIME(2,30,0))))
```

If you've got dates, replace all but the first A2 reference with `$A2-INT($A2)` to extract the time.